# Rendering a map with raster tiles and vector data in D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to render a map with US states (vector data) in a basemap (raster tiles). The map should also include zoom as I plan to add zoom transformations with different counties and other boundary types. Please excuse my code as I am a real novice in JS/D3js. I found a great example on the internet and I based my code on it, I hope it makes sense.

The raster tiles get rendered but not the vector data at all. Can anyone help me? I feel I am very close, thanks :)

```
function testMap() {

var states = d3.json("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/us-atlas@3/states-10m.json").then(topology => topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.states).features)

var width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;

var map = d3.select(".visualizations").append("div")
    .attr("class", "map")

var layer = map.append("div")
    .attr("class", "layer");

const svg = d3.select(".layer").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var g = d3.select("svg").append("g")

const projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .scale(1 / (2 * Math.PI))
    .translate([0, 0]);

const render = d3.geoPath(projection);

const tile = d3.tile()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .tileSize(512);

const zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 << 10, 1 << 15])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", ({transform}) => zoomed(transform));

let image = svg.append("g")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none")
    .selectAll("image");

var initialScale = 1 << 12
var initialCenter = [-98 - 35 / 60, 39 + 50 / 60]

svg
    .call(zoom)
    .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
        .translate(width / 2, height / 2)
        .scale(-initialScale)
        .translate(...projection(initialCenter))
        .scale(-1));

function zoomed(transform) {
  const tiles = tile(transform);

  image = image.data(tiles, d => d).join("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return "http://" + "abc"[d[1] % 3] + ".tile.openstreetmap.org/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png"; })
      .attr("x", ([x]) => (x + tiles.translate[0]) * tiles.scale)
      .attr("y", ([, y]) => (y + tiles.translate[1]) * tiles.scale)
      .attr("width", tiles.scale)
      .attr("height", tiles.scale);

  projection
      .scale(transform.k / (2 * Math.PI))
      .translate([transform.x, transform.y]);

svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(states.features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class","mapFocus")
      .attr("d", render)

// I tried the option below but does not work either
//   path.attr("d", render(feature));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace the code of the `zoomed` function.

Use code :

```
function zoomed(transform) {
  const tiles = tile(transform);

  image = image.data(tiles, d => d).join("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return "http://" + "abc"[d[1] % 3] + ".tile.openstreetmap.org/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png"; })
      .attr("x", ([x]) => (x + tiles.translate[0]) * tiles.scale)
      .attr("y", ([, y]) => (y + tiles.translate[1]) * tiles.scale)
      .attr("width", tiles.scale)
      .attr("height", tiles.scale);

  projection
      .scale(transform.k / (2 * Math.PI))
      .translate([transform.x, transform.y]);

  svg.selectAll("path.mapFocus")
      .data(states)
      .join("path")
      .attr("class","mapFocus")
      .attr("d", render);
}
```